# R - all matching pairs of vector's elements

Tags: r

I am looking to identify all possible pairwise matching of a vector's elements. I will not now the number of elements of the vector, so length(vector)=n, but I will only know that n is even. The order does not matter but each time, the pairs need to add up to the initial vector.

To give an example if `x<-c(1,2,3,4)` the answer is `3`, and namely:

```
1) (1,2)(3,4)
2) (1,3)(2,4)
3) (1,4)(2,3)
```

There are quite a few similar threads, but I am missing the part where the pairs are grouped to form the initial vector.

Thanks!

Comment: For your specific example, you could do something like `res <- combn(x, 2, simplify = FALSE) ; indx <- choose(length(x), 2) ;Map(c, res[1:(indx/2)], res[indx:(indx/2+1)])`, though I'm not sure how you wan to generalize this for longer vectors. For example, for `x <- 1:5`, pairwise combinations won't be able to fill a complete vector of 5 values each time

Comment: Anyway, the only functionality that makes sense to me is something like `vecfunc <- function(x){
  L <- length(x);
  indx <- choose(L, L/2) ;
  res <- combn(x, L/2, simplify = FALSE) ;
  Map(c, res[1:(indx/2)], res[indx:(indx/2+1)])  
}` which will accept only even length vectors. Then you can even do `x<-1:8;
vecfunc(x)
`

Comment: I'm utterly confused as to how 3 sets of pairs is "all possible pairwise matchings" given your example `x`

Answer (score 1):

Each ordered pairing of n elements (where n is even) is equivalent to a random permutation of `(1:n) %% (n/2)`. In addition, since the order of pairs doesn't matter, permutations that are equal up to labelling are actually equivalent. For example, `c(1,1,0,0)` is equivalent to `c(0,0,1,1)`- both of them are pairing the first two elements together and the last two elements together. So we can get the unique set by expanding every permutation, then re-labelling each permutation's elements in the order that they appear, and then taking just the unique ones from the result:

```
library(magrittr)
library(combinat)

all_pairings <- function(n) {
    if (n %% 2 != 0)
        stop("n must be even")
    allperms <- permn((1:n) %% (n/2))
    allperms %<>% lapply(. %>% factor(levels=unique(.)) %>% as.numeric)
    unique(allperms)
}
```

This gives us the correct result for n=4:

```
> all_pairings(4)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 2 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 2 2
```

To actually get the pairs, use the `split` function:

```
> lapply(all_pairings(4), split, x=letters[1:n])
[[1]]
[[1]]$`1`
[1] "a" "c"

[[1]]$`2`
[1] "b" "d"


[[2]]
[[2]]$`1`
[1] "a" "d"

[[2]]$`2`
[1] "b" "c"


[[3]]
[[3]]$`1`
[1] "a" "b"

[[3]]$`2`
[1] "c" "d"
```

If you only need the number of unique pairings and not a full listing of them, there is an explicit formula: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algebra/apr2/LpermRep.htm

In this case, the formula for unique pairings of N elements would be `factorial(n) / 2^(n/2) / factorial(n/2)`. The first term represents all the permutations, the second term represents the redundancy due to equivalent within-pair reorderings, and the third term represents redundancy due to reordering of the pairs.

```
num_pairings <- function(n) {
    if (any(n %% 2 != 0))
        stop("n must be even")
    factorial(n) / (2^(n/2)) / factorial(n/2)
}


> n <- seq(2,20, by=2); data.frame(n=n, NumPairings=num_pairings(n))
data.frame with 10 rows and 2 columns
           n NumPairings
   <numeric>   <numeric>
1          2           1
2          4           3
3          6          15
4          8         105
5         10         945
6         12       10395
7         14      135135
8         16     2027025
9         18    34459425
10        20   654729075
```